# Helm3 loses the revision

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I installed a chart on a K8s cluster using helm3. Later I context switched to another Kubernetes cluster, did a few things, and then switched back on the original cluster in which I deployed the chart. I find that `helm list` is not listing any releases (which is very strange). However, I find that the secret in which helm stores release info still exists in the current namespace.

```sh
sh.helm.release.v1.my-chart.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      66m
```

Is there a way to recover the release information for the helm client from the secret, given that all the info about releases is stored in the secret?

I'm using the following version:

```sh
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.2", GitCommit:"d878d4d45863e42fd5cff6743294a11d28a9abce", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.8"}
```

Comment: Did you try to recreate the problem. Did you make sure that I am running helm list on the correct namespace ?

Comment: Not yet. Yes I am fairly confident that it was on the same namespace. I ran `helm list` on default branch and it didn't list anything. But when i list secrets, it showed that secret. I must reproduce it.

Comment: Did you manage to reproduce - any positive results ?

Answer (score 1):

> then switched back on the original cluster in which I deployed the chart. I find that helm list is not listing any releases (which is very strange)

That's indeed very strange .

> `sh.helm.release.v1.my-chart.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      66m`

This is all Helm should need to find your release. You can inspect it  if it's corrupted.

```sh
$ kubectl get secret sh.helm.release.v1.mychart.v1 -o=json | jq '.data.release' | tr -d '"' | base64 -d | base64 -d > myrelease.gz
$ gunzip myrelease.gz
$ cat myrelease
```

You can also run `helm ls` on all namespaces, to double-check that you are not missing the release in a different namespace.

```sh
$ helm ls -A
```

✌️

Comment: ugh I deleted the cluster :( I will try to recreate the problem. Does helm simply read the secret to get the cluster state? I am very sure that I checked the namespaces to make sure that I am running helm list on the correct namespace.